# Square Reporting API

Tags: square-connect

Does anyone know if there is an API for adding items to reporting for Square? I want to check out via another method but remove items from inventory in Square; that way it can reflect inventory was changed in the Square reporting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Square's Inventory APIs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#post-inventory-variationid) to make inventory changes with each sale. You can also use the [Orders endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-orders) to itemize e-commerce transactions so that you see the items in Dashboard and on customer receipts.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks